# ElasticSearch query combining string match and nested field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query that looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
                "query": "Lorem*",
                "fields": ["search_names", "name^2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Against documents that look like this.

```
{
        "member_name" : "Lorem Ipsum",
        "complaint_periods" : [
            {
                "period": "01/01/2001 - 31/12/2001",
                "complaints": "10"
            },
            {
                "period": "01/01/2002 - 31/12/2002",
                "complaints": "0"
            },
            {
                "period": "01/01/2003 - 31/12/2003",
                "complaints": "3"
            },
            {
                "period": "01/01/2004 - 31/12/2004",
                "complaints": "100"
            }
         ],
        "search_names" : [
            "Lorem Ipsum",
            "dolor sit amet",
            "varius augue",
            "Aliquam fringilla"
        ]
}
```

So I'm able to retrieve documents based on how close their name, and search names are to my query.

The requirement is, a text search box should retrieve the closest name match to the query, however, given relatively similar names, a document with a number of complaints above a threshold of 10 in a passed time period, should appear higher in the search results than those with less than 10.

So I need to pass a key for the time period, e.g. "01/01/2001 - 31/12/2001", and boost the documents score if the complaint value for that period is > 10.

Current index mapping looks like this.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "member_name": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "search_names": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "complaint_periods": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "period": {
                    "type": "text",
                },
                "complaints": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently reading into Nested queries as a possible solution...but I'm fairly fresh to ES so keen to get opinions on the types of queries/structure I should be using to achieve this.

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide your index mapping and anything which you have tried on which we can build solution

Comment: Updated my question with the index mapping; I'm reading into 'Nested queries' but at present I don't have a partial solution. Looking for advice on what kinds of queries to use and how the data should be structured/indexed based on the the output requirements and what the data looks like.

Comment: look like you provided partial mapping, I can't see the mapping for date and complaints fields, also it would be great if you can share a postman collection with all the required API to quickly reprouce your issue

Comment: Apologies; my index mapping was actually not valid. ES still returned results for me so didn't seem to be a problem. I've updated it again. 
Appreciate the effort to investigate but at this stage I wouldn't really be comfortable to share access to the API with third parties.

Comment: we don't need access to your APIs, we just need minimum information for us to debug issue :-)

Comment: one suggestion, complain period is a date range, so it would be better to use `date` datatype to store them

Comment: Thanks, I was actually able to solve this one, and I've posted my answer for others. 
In my case, although it appears the 'complaint_period' is a date, its actually treated more like a category, so I've switched it over to 'keyword' type which was needed in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I was able to solve this with the following query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Lorem*",
          "fields": ["search_names", "member_name^2"]
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "complaint_periods",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                      { "term" : {"complaint_periods.period" : "01/01/2001 - 31/12/2001"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've switched over to using a boolean query since according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> A query that matches documents matching boolean combinations of other queries

So as I understand this, the first part of my query indicates that the result "must" contain a string match against my query in one of 2 fields.

The second part is a nested query. While my data appears to be a date, its actually stored and queried like a category, so I switched the complaint_period type over to a 'keyword' type instead of 'text'. This allows me to use it in a 'term' query (exact text match, categorical).

Since the nested query is 'should' the result does not HAVE to match, but if it does it should boost the score and push it further up the list of results.

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) on nested queries also have examples that would allow me to boost based on the number of complaints e.g:

```
{ "range" : {"complaint_periods.complaints" : {"gt" : 5}} }
```

Which I may need to add later on.